# What is running on my Google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

There is a lot of activity on my Google Compute engine API. It's less than 1 request per second which probably keeps me in the free zone but how do I figure out what is running and if I should stop it?

I have some pub/sub topics and a cloud function to copy data into a dataStore database.  But even if I am not publishing any data (for days), I still get activity on the compute engine?  Can I disable it or will it stop my cloud functions?

Comment: Use of the Compute Engine API doesn't cost money regardless of how many requests you make. You do pay for resources (such as VMs) created.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on billing.  I discovered it was required for viewing the Google Datastore (though not required for writing to the datastore).

Answer (score 0):

I believe, [Ops agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent) provided by Google might help you monitor the instance In a way that is easy to understand.

Below are some monitoring features including:
System metrics collected with no configuration. Metrics collected include: cpu metrics, disk metrics, iis metrics (Windows only), interface metrics,gpu metrics (Linux only), memory metrics, mssql metrics (Windows only), pagefile metrics (Windows only), swap metrics, network metrics processes metrics, agent self metrics

**Third-party application support**

- Curated integrations for third-party application metrics, which collect common app metrics and offer sample dashboards and alert policies.
- Collection of Prometheus metrics from applications running on Compute Engine.
- Collection of OpenTelemetry Protocol (OTLP) metrics and traces from applications instrumented with OpenTelemetry SDKs.
- Collection of NVIDIA Data Center GPU Manager (DCGM) metrics.

Perhaps, you can use the following command to view information about active processes. > ps aux